# Is there a CMS for Lift?

Tags: scala, content-management-system, lift

I'm trying to develop a form of social network in Lift, could someone please suggest a good starting point without reinventing (most of) the wheel, e.g., user management? Is there a CMS available?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a CMS solution by David Pollak called Hoisted. You can find it [here](http://hoisted.org) and [here](https://github.com/dpp/hoisted). As for user management system you'll have to hand roll one using lift's authentication features.

Answer (score 1):

I also stumbled over orsacms, though I didn't have a closer look.